how to convert string to datetime in azure data factory
In a Copy data activity , I am reading data from Stored procedure (SQL Server) and passing a datTime parameter. In this parameter I am using an expression formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-10),'yyyy-MM-dd') which returns the date in yyyy-mm-dd in the String format.
I wanted to convert it to the Datetime but couldn't find any proper functions to do the same.
i tried a solution using DataFlows with Derived Column but this required changing the whole pipeline to DataFlow and currently it is not a feasible for me.


In copy activity, select the stored procedure name from the drop down or enter the name manually.
Then select import parameters.
In the imported parameter, check if the type of the parameter is datetime. Change the type, if it is different.

Give the expression as dynamic content in the value text box. @formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-10),'yyyy-MM-dd')

This would make sure that date value is passed as date type only in stored procedure and not as a string.
